# disable FAB fade animation

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, floating-action-button

I have this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="me.myapplication.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When I scroll up and down the FAB fades in and out -> [video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7PnmR9Iza92T3NxWjc1MmVLZzA)

Is it possible to disable this fade animation?

Comment: What exactly would you like to have? Collapsing toolbar with always pinned FAB? Should it decrease its size?

Comment: For future readers: the answer clarifies the question. I found this question+answer as I was trying to figure out why the FloatingActionButton's behavior_autoHide attribute wasn't working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it :-)

The [`Behavior`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) of the [`FloatingActionButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.Behavior.html) has a [`behavior_autoHide`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.Behavior.html#attr_android.support.design:behavior_autoHide) option.

The problem was that I tried to set this option in the layout xml. But the `FloatingActionButton.Behavior` did not read this option because Android calls the wrong constructor.

```
public Behavior() {
    super();
    mAutoHideEnabled = AUTO_HIDE_DEFAULT;
}
```

You have to set the `Behavior` in the layout xml too. Now Android calls the right constructor and the `behavior_autoHide` flag is read.

```
public Behavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.FloatingActionButton_Behavior_Layout);
    mAutoHideEnabled = a.getBoolean(
            R.styleable.FloatingActionButton_Behavior_Layout_behavior_autoHide,
            AUTO_HIDE_DEFAULT);
    a.recycle();
}
```

The important part of your layout xml should look like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    app:behavior_autoHide="false"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$Behavior"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
```

Comment: Great work. It's cool that merely adding the `app:layout_behavior` line is enough to work around the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the full text search: Ctrl+Shift+F to find "FloatingActionButton.Behavior". The successor of this class defines the behavior of FAB, so you can remove lines that handle this fading. 
If you do not find it, try to find just "Behavior" in case if it is applied to Coordinator layout and not to the FAB directly.

Comment: I looked into this bahavior it has a auto hide option but this is not what I looking for (or I use it the wrong way)

Comment: Could you please add this class into your question too?